# making a log in as user in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

i want to know if there is any way to simulate the login as user and make the session for that user .i want my help-desk to see the site from users vision so they need to log in as user as long as i cant show the user s password to the admin (its not possible as far as i know if its not that would be a good solution too ). i want to place a button with some text for example :

```
LoginAsThisUser
```

and when my help desk clicks on the button he logs in as the user is there any way to do that ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, and it's fairly simple to do. All you need to do is to create a route, something like this:

```
Route::get('admin/login-as-user/{id}', 'Admin\UserController@loginAsUser')->name('login.as.user');
```

After that, pass the route to your `LoginAsThisUser` button with desired `user id` :

```
<a href="{{route('login.as.user'), $user->id}}" class="btn btn-default">LoginAsThisUser</a>
```

And create a function in your controller:

```
public function loginAsUser($id)
{
     $user = User::findOrFail($id);
     Auth::login($user);
     return redirect('/');
}
```

Note: this is not tested, let me know if you encounter any errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

//use user_id
Auth::loginUsingId(1);

// Login and "remember" the given user...
Auth::loginUsingId(1, true);

$user=User::find($userId);


//use Authenticatable user
Auth::login($user);

// Login and "remember" the given user...
Auth::login($user, true);
```

also use 
`Auth::guard('notDeafault')->login($user);`

if you want switch default guard

Answer (score 1):

With the Auth facade, you can use the loginUsingId method

```php
Auth::loginUsingId($user_id);
```

This method allows you to force login without a password. But it does not allow you to retrieve cookies or cache from your user's browser that may impact their viewing.